# Physical body not responding in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

I just started making my first Corona game, and have already run into a problem.  In the code below, the crate is supposed to bounce off the line that the user has drawn, but for some reason, the crate just keeps moving, as if the line is not even there.  If anyone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 local physics = require "physics"
 physics.start()

local crate1 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth/2,display.contentHeight/2, 40,40)
physics.addBody( crate1, { density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=.4} )
crate1.bodyType = "dynamic"
crate1.isBodyActive = true
crate1:setFillColor( 1,0,.3)



local line
lineGroup = display.newGroup()
local prevX,prevY
local isDrawing = false
local i = 0

local function distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2)
   local dist_x = x2 - x1
   local dist_y = y2 - y1
   local distanceBetween = math.sqrt((dist_x*dist_x) + (dist_y*dist_y))
   return distanceBetween
end

local function drawLine(e)
if(e.phase == "began") then
  if(line) then
    lineGroup:remove(1)
    line = nil
  end

  prevX = e.x
  prevY = e.y
  isDrawing = true
elseif(e.phase == "moved") then
  local distance = distanceBetween(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
  if(isDrawing and distance < 100) then
     if(line) then lineGroup:remove(1) end
     line = display.newLine(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
     line:setStrokeColor( 0.5,0,1 )
     line.strokeWidth = 5

    local dist_x = e.x - prevX
    local dist_y = e.y - prevY
    physics.addBody(line, "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce     = 2, shape = {0,0, dist_x, dist_y, 0, 0} } )
    lineGroup:insert(line)
 end
elseif(e.phase == "ended") then
  isDrawing = false
 end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",drawLine)
```

Comment: I get an error saying" corona cannot index a 'physical body' of nearly no area".  I tried this code on the 2013 version of corona though, and it worked. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         physics.addBody(line, "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce     = 2, shape = {0,0, dist_x, dist_y, 0, 0} } )
```

Delete :  shape = {0,0, dist_x, dist_y, 0, 0}

Change to :

```
physics.addBody(line, "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 2 } )
```

I already tried this in the emulator and it works.